# Seeking name for an order raising operator in Higher Order Arithmetic.

Tags: proof-theory, peano-arithmetic, terminology

Any class $X$ of order $j$ in HOA is in bijection with the order $j+1$ class built up from singletons $\{x\}$ of natural numbers $x$ just the way that $X$ is built up from the numbers $x$.  And of course this can be iterated any number of times.

Is there a standard, or at least published, name for this order raising operation?

Comment: Your order-raising operation doesn't actually raise the order when $j$ is a limit ordinal. 

Comment: Yes.  In fact I want it for finite order arithmetic.

Comment: The letter $i$ is often used for the map $x\mapsto\lbrace x\rbrace$. I think this goes back to Russel & Whitehead or even earlier than that...